# Resultset getString throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

I got exception when trying to retrieve String value from ResultSet. This happens after I added two new columns image_url and icon_url to the table (default null) and trying to retrieve the new added columns.
The table create statement is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `examples` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`event_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`session_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`location` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`button_label` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`hidden` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`image_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`icon_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=427 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The query is pretty simple, just query all fields from examples object:

```
@Override
public List<Example> getExamples(Integer eventId) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT * FROM examples WHERE event_id= ?",
            new Object[]{eventId},
            (rs, rowNum) -> {
                 Example ex = new Example();
                 ex.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                 ex.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                 ex.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                 ex.setExpoId(rs.getInt("expo_id"));
                 ex.setSessionId(rs.getString("session_id"));
                 ex.setLocation(rs.getString("location"));
                 ex.setStartDate(rs.getString("start_date"));
                 ex.setEndDate(rs.getString("end_date"));
                 ex.setUrl(rs.getString("url"));
                 ex.setButtonLabel(rs.getString("button_label"));
                 ex.setHidden(rs.getBoolean("hidden"));
                 ex.setImageUrl(rs.getString("image_url")); //throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                 ex.setIconUrl(rs.getString("icon_url")); // throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            });
}
```

The exception go away if I update all image_url and icon_url to empty string instead of null value.

I'm using HikariCP to config and manage the Datasouce:

```
   @Bean(name = "dataSouce")
   public DataSource dataSouce() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("ds.url"));
    config.setUsername(env.getProperty("ds.username"));
    config.setPassword(env.getProperty("ds.password"));
    config.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("ds.driver.classname"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("useLocalSessionState", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("useLocalTransactionState", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("rewriteBatchedStatements", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cacheResultSetMetadata", "false");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cacheServerConfiguration", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("elideSetAutoCommits", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("maintainTimeStats", "false");
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

I've been debugging this for hours but no luck of finding what's going on, also pretty new to HikariCP so not sure if it have some effect to caching the query results. The complete exception trace are below:

```
2017-08-14 12:09:53.020 [http-apr-8080-exec-2] WARN  example.MvcLogger - Handler execution resulted in exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 939
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.Buffer.readInteger(Buffer.java:284)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.BinaryBufferRow.getValue(BinaryBufferRow.java:231)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:880)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:892)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at com.playstation.sony.otg.service.impl.EventsServiceImpl.lambda$getExamples$2(EventsServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:708)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787)
at com.playstation.sony.otg.service.impl.EventsServiceImpl.getExamples(EventsServiceImpl.java:158)
at com.playstation.sony.otg.controller.AdminController.eventIdExamplesGet(AdminController.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.playstation.sony.otg.logging.logging.LoggerFilter.doFilter(LoggerFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.playstation.sony.otg.config.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:22)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It might be some very dumb mistake I've made since I've leave industry for years and back, any help appreciated!

Comment: what's your MySql version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84084) on `MySQL Connector / J 6.0.5` with same exception which was closed

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.Buffer.readInteger(Buffer.java:284)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.BinaryBufferRow.getValue(BinaryBufferRow.java:227)
```

The comment:

> An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException was thrown when a server-side
>   prepared statement was used and there was a NULL in a BLOB, TEXT, or
>   JSON type column in the ResultSet

This was fixed in [Connector / J 8.0.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-7.html#connector-j-8-0-7-bug)

> An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException was thrown when a server-side
>   prepared statement was used and there was a NULL in a BLOB, TEXT, or
>   JSON type column in the ResultSet. (Bug #25215008, Bug #84084)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using Mysql connector 6.0.6. After switch to 8.0.7 [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.7-dmr) problem solved. Is it safe to use that version in production? Or I should downgrade to 5.1.x?